# How to maintain TableView selection within Timeline?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to maintain my selection in a TableView in a background Timeline task.

When I set breakpoints, the data is correct and my RowSelection callback is being triggered. I am utilizing a Timeline because I thought it handled GUI refreshing without exceptions such like in `Timers`. This is my code:

```
private void initializeAutoRefresh() {
    this.autoRefreshTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), (ActionEvent event) -> {
        if (entries != null) {
            entries.clear();
            tableOfGames.getItems().clear();
            populateGameTable(); // Done through Web Service
            System.out.println("Refreshed data.");

            if (selectedGame!= null) {
                tableOfGames.requestFocus();
                tableOfGames.getSelectionModel().select(entries.indexOf(selectedGame));
            }
        }
    }));
    this.autoRefreshTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    autoRefreshTimeline.play();
}
```

The selected row is not maintained after a refresh. The desired behavior is to have the row selected and in blue, like convention. However, the GUI does not persist after this refresh, which, according to the Timeline is every 10 seconds.

Comment: You haven't posted the relevant code.  Where is this value determined: selectedGame?  What is the contents of the tableview?

Comment: It's in my original post, the selected row callback sets this selectedGame variable.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How is `selectedGame` set? Does the item class implement `equals`? Does `populateGameTable` fill `entries`? Why do you communicate with a web service on the JavaFX application thread?